# Как перенести данные из одной таблицы, сохранив связи

Tags: sql

В общем есть одна большая таблица, ее разделили на несколько для удобства и построили реляции. Теперь нужно перенести данные из этой большой таблицы в остальные, но нужно сохранить связь между данными, раньше в одной таблице связь данных была благодаря тому, что все данные хранились вместе, но так как были созданы новые таблицы, то и были созданы Primary Key и Foreign Keys, если просто переносить с помощью INSERT то получится, что связи потеряются.

Comment: давайте с примерами конкретных данных и таблиц. что было, как разделили, в чем проблема вышла.

Comment: если связь один к одному, то что мешает вам сделать одинаковые ключи во всех таблицах, которые равны исходному?

Comment: Insert в master-таблицу из source-таблицы. Затем insert в slave-таблицу, а в качестве источника source join master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример переноса.

Исходная таблица. `id` - синтетика, и сохранения не требует.

```
CREATE TABLE source (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- не сохраняем
  grp INT, 
  val INT
  );
INSERT INTO source VALUES
(1,1,1),
(3,1,2),
(6,1,3),
(7,2,4),
(2,2,5),
(4,2,6);
SELECT * FROM source;
```

| id | grp | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | 4 |

Переносим main-данные.

```
CREATE TABLE main_group (
  grp_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  grp INT
  ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
INSERT INTO main_group (grp)
SELECT DISTINCT grp
FROM source;
SELECT * FROM main_group;
```

| grp_id | grp |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 |

Переносим slave-данные, используем связывание для получение нового значения ключа.

```
CREATE TABLE slave_value (
  val_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  grp_id INT,
  val INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (grp_id) REFERENCES main_group (grp_id)) AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;
INSERT INTO slave_value (grp_id, val)
SELECT main_group.grp_id, source.val
FROM source
JOIN main_group USING (grp);
SELECT * FROM slave_value;
```

| val_id | grp_id | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 10 | 1 |
| 21 | 11 | 5 |
| 22 | 10 | 2 |
| 23 | 11 | 6 |
| 24 | 10 | 3 |
| 25 | 11 | 4 |

Проверяем соответствие исходных данных и результата.

```
SELECT grp, val FROM source ORDER BY 1,2;

SELECT main_group.grp, slave_value.val
FROM main_group
JOIN slave_value USING (grp_id) ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| grp | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

| grp | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Vqo7jcB)